# Как вводить длинные числа в masm?

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Здарвствуйте. Мне нужно ввести число большой размерности в консоль, вычесть из первого второе и напечатать результат. Как вычесть два больших числа я разобрлся. Вывести число тоже понимаю как, но с вводом и возникает больше всего проблем. Я не понимаю, как записать такое число в массив. Можете подсказать, как это сделать ?

```
.386 ; Тип процессора
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap: none
include c:\masm\masm32\include\windows.inc
include c:\masm\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include c:\masm\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
include c:\masm\masm32\include\user32.inc

includelib c:\masm\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib c:\masm\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib c:\masm\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data 
a db 14 dup(?) ; 14 байт 
b db 14 dup(?); 14 байт
r db 14 dup(?) 

input_a db  "input a: ", 0
input_b db  "input b: ", 0
format  db  "%hl", 0
.code
start:
;input

MOV EAX, DWORD PTR a[0]
SUB EAX, DWORD PTR b[0]
MOV DWORD PTR r[0], EAX

MOV EAX, DWORD PTR a[4]
SBB EAX, DWORD PTR b[4]
MOV DWORD PTR r[4], EAX

MOV EAX, DWORD PTR a[8]
SBB EAX, DWORD PTR b[8]
MOV DWORD PTR r[8], EAX

MOV AX, WORD PTR a[12]
MOV BX, WORD PTR b[12]
SBB AX, BX
MOV WORD PTR r[12], AX

;output
push NULL
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Comment: Слишком общая постановка задачи, отсюда уточняющий вопрос:
Почему Вы используете байтовый тип числа и строите из него массив, а не берете двойное слово или даже q- слово?